# Running long/complex commands using Python

Tags: python

Is there any easy way to run complex/long shell commands.  i just need namespace . python was not happy with Awk .  and how to store the output in variable in below example ..or store in file is better.  ?

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen('kubectl get ns ', shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen('grep mynamespace', shell=True, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
p3 = subprocess.Popen('cut -d" " -f 1', shell=True, stdin=p2.stdout)

p1.stdout.close()
out, err = p3.communicate()
```

Comment: as an aside, why use grep/awk/sed/cut when you can do the string manipulation in python?  You *can*, but it feels like the wrong paradigm.  Not that I've anything against such tools, but they're not that easy to use from python, as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Kubernetes Python Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) to accomplish that task:

```py
# python -m pip install kubernetes
from kubernetes import client, config

# Load ~/.kube/config

config.load_kube_config()

c = client.CoreV1Api()
name_space_list = c.list_namespace()
for name_space in name_space_list.items:
    print(name_space.metadata.name)
```

I often avoid using subprocess as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst @PraysonWDaniel's answer is probably the way to go---use a library if you can---there is no reason not to do this text manipulation in python if you're going to do it:

```py
from subprocess import run

def get_namespace():
    p = run(["kubectl", "get", "ns"], capture_output=True, encoding="utf8")
    ns = next(l for l in p.stdout.splitlines() if "mynamespace" in l)
    return ns.split()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks Guys . i think k8s client will be good option .  Thanks 2e0byo as well .